Apache 2.4 WebServer Configuration : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I managed to deploy a map server:

I want to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings in a way that it allows only specific IP Addresses to visualize the map
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName server.name
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

   # disable proxy for the /font-family sub-directory
   # must be placed on top of the other ProxyPass directive
   ProxyPass /font-family !
   Alias "/font-family" "/var/www/font-family"
   #HTTP proxy
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   # Only allow authorizied domains to fetch resources on this tile server
   #SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(server\.name)$" origin_is=$0
   #Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin
   #Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is

   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
   Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"

   #Header always set Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests
   #Header merge Vary Origin


   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tileserver-gl.error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tileserver-gl.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

#<Directory "/">
    #<RequireAny> 
        #Require ip my_local_ip_address
    #</RequireAny>
#</Directory>

<Location "/">
    Require all granted
</Location>

I tried with both <Directory><RequireAny>Require ip my_local_ip_address</RequireAny></Directory> and <Location "/">Require all granted</Location>
, but, in both cases I get this error message:
map.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://map.server.name/styles/basic-preview/style.json'
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.

and the rendering of the html file does not output the map:

I tried also with :
<Directory />
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>

and, then, with :
<Location  "/.*">
    Require all granted
</Location>

And also in this way:
<Directory "/">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/index.hml">
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip yyy.yy.y.y
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>

but got the same error message and the same blank output.
Apache2 Version: Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
What am I missing and/or doing wrong with the Apache2 WebServer configuration? How to make it work?
